# Check if selection is equal to a predetermined range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have written a bit of code for that has the following purpose: a user must select a range on Sheet1, then will press a button to which a macro is assigned. The macro will then check if the range the user has selected is equal to a predetermined range, also on Sheet1. If both ranges are the same, then the macro will select Sheet2 and complete other tasks. If the ranges are not equal, then the macro will stop. Here is the code:

```
Sub Example_1()

    Dim OriginalSelection As Range
    Set OriginalSelection = Selection

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("S8:AC8") = OriginalSelection Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        'The macro will do other things here
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

This said, whenever I try to run the macro, I get the following error:

> Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch

Does anybody know where the problem lies? I am still trying to wrap my head around VBA!

Thanks :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "if both ranges are the same"?

Comment: For example, if the predetermined range is S8:AC8 on Sheet1, and if the user selects range S8:AC8 on Sheet1, then both those ranges are the same. I am not talking about cell content here. Sorry if it is ambiguous, I am still learning the appropriate jargon!

Comment: OK, try this `If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("S8:AC8").address = OriginalSelection.address`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To check if the sheet is the same too, you can use the full address:

```
If Selection.Address(0, 0, , 1) = "[Book1]Sheet1!S8:AC8" Then
```

or

```
If Selection.Address(0, 0) = "S8:AC8" And Selection.Parent.Name = "Sheet1" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try comparing the `Range.Address` with one line:

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("S8:AC8").Address(True, True, xlA1, True) = OriginalSelection.Address(True, True, xlA1, True) Then
```

The fourth parameter `External = True` will return the the full Range including the `Workbook.Name` and `Sheet.Name`